# Как передавать текстовые данные посредством rtmp?

Tags: javascript, html, сервер, nginx, rtmp

Собрал сервер nginx с модулем rtmp, видео и аудио передаются на ура.

Можно ли как то передать через rtmp-поток текстовые данные для дальнейшей обработки?

В моей задаче должна на сайт передаваться онлайн-трансляция с сопутствующими текстовыми данными. Если да, то как, если нет, то что вы мне посоветуете?

Comment: Протокол это поддерживает, хотя он и проприетарный, что добавляет трудностей. Но вам надо написать приложение, которое будет эти данные отдавать. И оно должно уметь обслуживать RTMP-соединения.